# How should I use tools:overrideLibrary?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, build.gradle, android-manifest

So this error message appears:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.2] C:\Users\DELL.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2bfce4225340219067212fe3be9c89b6\transformed\jetified-firebase-firestore-24.1.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

I keep getting the same error eventho I applied the suggested changes. Another problem is that it doesn't save the changes. After applying the changes, I get the same error. Upon checking I see the same code before the change, as if it doesn't save the changes(Yes, I have saved the changes).

The build.gradle file:

```
 minSdkVersion 23
 targetSdkVersion 32
```

The Android.Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.google.firebase.firestore"
    android:versionName="24.1.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
```

Like I said, I've applied the following changes: change minSdkVersion to 23, change targetSdkVersion to 32 and addes the tools:overrideLibrary line. But I keep getting the same error as thou nothing has changed. It goes back to this default code as shown above. Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t see in your manifest in the uses-sdk tag the lines tools: overrideLibrary for the required library